# How to get the number of workers(executors) in PySpark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to use this parameter, so how can I get the number of workers?
Like in Scala, I can call `sc.getExecutorMemoryStatus` to get the available number of workers. But in PySpark, it seems there's no API exposed to get this number.

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of the other. I would like to know how many executors have become available to the driver, even before any rdds have been created, when running on Mesos. Pretty annoying, but I ended up parsing the ui: import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html("http://localhost:4040/executors")[1]
len(df[df['Executor ID'] != 'driver'])

Comment: Quick answer, to get the number of cores:  sc._jsc.sc().getExecutorMemoryStatus().size()

Comment: Voted to reopen, as the original question refers to EMR nodes and this to Spark executors. While this question answers the former, the former is less generic. P.S. The accepted answer here is plain and simply wrong - both in the result and in the assumptions.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In scala, `getExecutorStorageStatus` and `getExecutorMemoryStatus` both return the number of executors including driver.
like below example snippet

```
/** Method that just returns the current active/registered executors
        * excluding the driver.
        * @param sc The spark context to retrieve registered executors.
        * @return a list of executors each in the form of host:port.
        */
       def currentActiveExecutors(sc: SparkContext): Seq[String] = {
         val allExecutors = sc.getExecutorMemoryStatus.map(_._1)
         val driverHost: String = sc.getConf.get("spark.driver.host")
         allExecutors.filter(! _.split(":")(0).equals(driverHost)).toList
       }
```

[But In python api it was not implemented](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext)

@DanielDarabos [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768642/getting-number-of-visible-nodes-in-pyspark) also confirms this.

The equivalent to this in python...

```
sc.getConf().get("spark.executor.instances")
```

*Edit (python) :*

```
%python
sc = spark._jsc.sc() 
n_workers =  len([executor.host() for executor in sc.statusTracker().getExecutorInfos() ]) -1

print(n_workers)
```

As Danny mentioned in the comment if you want to cross verify them you can use the below statements.

```
%python

sc = spark._jsc.sc() 

result1 = sc.getExecutorMemoryStatus().keys() # will print all the executors + driver available

result2 = len([executor.host() for executor in sc.statusTracker().getExecutorInfos() ]) -1

print(result1, end ='\n')
print(result2)
```

Example Result :

```
Set(10.172.249.9:46467)
0
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, but in my Pyspark, it showed  "SparkContext object has no attribute getConf"

Comment: I mean in you try in python equivalent syntax. not as it is...

Comment: I think its like this logger.info(sparkContext.getConf.getAll.mkString("\n")) will print all parameters appied out of that you can find number of executors as well

Comment: The python syntax is `sc._conf.get('spark.executor.instances')`. It returns a string.

Comment: Configured != reality :p

Comment: The actual number of executors may be lower than the configured amount, depending on available resources. That is why in Scala the above snippet is used and not the getConf().

Comment: Since this question is closed and this answer is wrong, I'll answer here:
`sc = spark_session._jsc.sc()`
`result1 = sc.getExecutorMemoryStatus().keys()`
`result2 = [executor.host() for executor in sc.statusTracker().getExecutorInfos()]`

Comment: Thanks Danny for your contribution. To be more precise, at least for running this on Databricks: `sc = spark._jsc.sc()` `n_workers = len([executor.host() for executor in sc.statusTracker().getExecutorInfos()]) - 1`

Comment: @Chiel  and Danny I editied/corrected the answer. Thanks

Comment: @Andrey : Thanks ... my bad its typo error. :-)

Comment: A quick note for Databricks there's also this key to check: `'spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.clusterTargetWorkers'`

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the number of executors by Spark REST API: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api

You can check `/applications/[app-id]/executors`, which returns *A list of all active executors for the given application*.

---

PS:
When `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled` is `true`, `spark.executor.instances` may not equals to the current available executors, but this API always returns the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

I instantiated the SparkContext this way **but no one of the solutions worked**:

```py
conf = SparkConf().setMaster(MASTER_CONNECTION_URL).setAppName('App name')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

So I changed my code to instantiate the SparkContext with `pyspark.sql.SparkSession` and everything worked fine:

```py
# Gets Spark context
conf = SparkConf().setMaster(MASTER_CONNECTION_URL).setAppName('App name')
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

# Gets the number of workers
spark = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
sc2 = spark._jsc.sc()
number_of_workers = len([executor.host() for executor in
                sc2.statusTracker().getExecutorInfos()]) - 1  # Subtract 1 to discard the master
```