# How to get number of executors from SparkSession in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, executor

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.getConf().get('spark.executor.instances') 
# Result: None

spark.conf.get('spark.executor.instances') 
# Result: java.util.NoSuchElementException: spark.executor.instances
```

I would like to see default value of the number of executors.

I looked into the ways to get the value and none of them worked.

[How to get the number of workers(executors) in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660907/how-to-get-the-number-of-workersexecutors-in-pyspark)

Comment: Have you tried `sc._jsc.sc().getExecutorMemoryStatus()`? Just make sure not to declare that in the beginning of the file (or at least put a sleep command if you do so)

Answer (score 0):

You can see specified configurations in Environment tab of application web UI or  get all specified parameters with following line:

```
spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()
```

According to [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

> only values explicitly specified through spark-defaults.conf,
> SparkConf, or the command line will appear. For all other
> configuration properties, you can assume the default value is used.

So if you did not assign a value to spark.executor.instances then you should check its default value on [Running Spark on Yarn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html)