# What hadoop configuration setting determines number of nodes available in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Not much experience with spark and trying to determine amount of available memory, number of executors, and nodes for a submitted spark job. Code just looks like...

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import time

sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("node_count_test").getOrCreate()
sparkSession._jsc.sc().setLogLevel("WARN")

# see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52516704/8236733 
print("Giving some time to let session start in earnest...")
time.sleep(15)
print("...done")

print("\n\nYou are using %d nodes in this session\n\n" % sparkSession._jsc.sc().getExecutorMemoryStatus().keySet().size())
```

and the output is...

```sh
Giving some time to let session start in earnest...
...done


You are using 3 nodes in this session
```

I would think this number should be the number of *data nodes* in the cluster, which I can see in ambari is 4, so I would think the output above would be 4. Can anyone tell me what determines the number of available nodes in spark or how I can scope into this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Spark 2.x with `DynamicAllocation` then the number of executors is governed by Spark. You can check the `spark-default.conf` for this value. In case you are not using `DynamicAllocation` then it is controlled by num-executors parameter.

The number of executors maps to Yarn Containers. one or more containers can run on a single data node based on resources availability

Comment: For others: Checking ambari spark configs tab and searching for dynamic allocation, found that it was enabled. From the docs (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation): "Whether to use dynamic resource allocation, which scales the number of executors registered with this application up and down based on the workload." So even though my cluster actually has 4 yarn containers (for each data node (that I had initially expected to see reflected in the spark executors count)), dynamic allocation lets spark choose the count used based on the workload as it processes